# problems with stdout and psexec.exe from sysinternals

Tags: c#

i have searched and read about issues with psexec.exe from sysinternals not working properly with c# and stdout. i am now trying to figure out how to just call a batch file that has the following instead of using System.Diagnostics.Process to call psexec:

test.bat contains the following line:

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -u user -p password ipconfig /all >c:\test.txt
```

test.txt will be saved on the host where i am running my c sharp app and executing psexec.

when i execute the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process psexec_run = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
psexec_run.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psexec_run.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c """ + cur_dir + @"\test\test.bat""";
psexec_run.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psexec_run.Start();
psexec_run.WaitForExit();
```

i see the cmd window pop up and it runs something but not sure what and goes away.

if i execute the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process psexec_run = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
psexec_run.StartInfo.FileName = cur_dir + "\\test\\psexec.exe";
psexec_run.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\hostname -u user -p password ipconfig /all";
psexec_run.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psexec_run.Start();
psexec_run.WaitForExit();
```

then i see the command window open and it runs psexec which takes quite a few secs and i quickly see my output i need, but i have no way of capturing the output or writing it to a file.

i guess my issue now is since psexec will not work with stdout how can i capture the output from the psexec command to write it to a file???

see the following link for the issues with psexec, the last reply on this url mentioned a way to write the process output to a file without using stdout, i'm newbie to c# i can't figure out how to write process output without use stdout :(

http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-fails-to-capture-stdout-when-launched-in-c_topic19333.html

based on response below i tried the following:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(cur_dir + "\\test\\psexec.exe",    @"\\hostname -u user -p password ipconfig /all");                   
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;         
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;         
psi.UseShellExecute = false;          
Process p = Process.Start(psi);          
StreamReader myStreamReader = p.StandardOutput;          
// Read the standard output of the spawned process.                         
string sOutput = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

i did ReadToEnd so i would make sure it got all the output, it DID NOT!! for some reason it only go the first line of ipconfig output that was it. Also the cmd window it opened up never closed for some reason. even with CreateNoWindow=true the code just hangs. so again something is wrong with psexec and stdout i think?? as i can run this code just fine using ipconfig /all command on the local host and not use psexec...

again i am looking to avoid stdout and somehow find a way to get the output from this command or unless there is something else i'm over looking? also, not to make more work for anyone, but if you d/l psexec.exe from sysinternals and test it with a command on a remote host you will see. i have spent 2 days on this one :( trying to figure out how to use psexec or find some other quick method to execute remote command on a host and get ouptput.

UPDATE:

i gave up on psexec in c# code, i saw many posts about psexec eating the output, having a child window process ,etcc
until my head hurt :) so i am trying to run a batch file and output to a file and it's not making sense...

i have a batch file test.bat with the following

```
psexec.exe \\\hostname -u name -p password ipconfig /all >c:\test.txt
```

when i run the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(cur_dir + @"\test\test.bat");

psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);

p.WaitForExit();
```

the cmd windows comes and goes really quickly and the test.txt file is created but is 0 bytes no info in it.

so if i run the batch file in a windows cmd line with the psexec command it works perfectly fine!!???

so then to verify psexec was the issue i changed the batch file to:

```
ipconfig /all >c:\test.txt
```

i execute my code above and it works fine creates the output in the test.txt file..???!!!!

why is not working with psexec am i missing something? if it's psexec, does anyone have
any recommendations for how i can execute a command on a remote windows host and get me the
output???

Comment: What happens if you did psexec_run.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\hostname -u user -p password ipconfig /all > C:\test.txt"

Comment: sometimes there is output on stderror too... so perhaps you need a second Streamreader taking p.StandardError and read that too.

Comment: 1. using >c:\test.txt does not work i even tried it on simple ipconfig command and does not generate the file not sure why.

Comment: 2. i tried reading stderror output and there was some output, only 1 line though just like with stdout gave... the output for stderror was just line showing copyright of the app etc..

Comment: see my update to my original question. thx

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "c sharp". The language is named "C#".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution. apparently psexec is NOT going to work in c sharp. so i came up with some wmi code to connect to a remote host and it's working PERFECTLY!!! :)

i used microsoft's WMICodeCreator.exe to create wmi code for C# for the process method on a remote host, wow that tool is amazing because wmi code is little confusing to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer to this problem that has worked for me.

Hopefully someone else will find it useful.

I have literally just spent the last two hours tearing my hair out with this. The psexec tool runs completely fine using a normal command prompt but when attempting to redirect the streams it truncates the output and you only get half output back.

In the end how I fixed my issue was a little bit of a hack. I piped the output of the command to a text file and read it back in to return it from the function.

I also has to set UseShellExecute to true. Without this it still wouldn't work. This had the unfortunate side effect of showing the console window. To get around that I set the window style to be hidden and hey presto it works!!!

Heres my code:

```
string ExecutePSExec(string command)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        string location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        // append output to file at the end of this string:
        string cmdWithFileOutput = string.Format("{0} >{1}temp.log 2>&1", command,location );


        // The flag /c tells "cmd" to execute what follows and exit
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + cmdWithFileOutput);

        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;       // have to set shell execute to true to 
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;      // as a window will be created set the window style to be hiddem

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();


        // now read file back.
        string filePath = string.Format("{0}temp.log", location);
        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }

    return result;
}
```

and its usage:

```
string command = @"psexec.exe -l -u domain\username -p password /accepteula \\192.168.1.3 netstat -a -n";

ExecutePSExec(command);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem. i was getting "Windows ip config. " as first line when i run with psexec. i tried with paexec it worked well. I used Marius's code.

Note: if you dont use first cmd / c in arguments command runs only on local computer even if you define target as \\remoteserver

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                        psi.Arguments = @"cmd/c C:\paexec.exe \\\192.168.2.5 -s  -u test.local\administrator -p Password1 cmd /c ipconfig";
                        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                        Process p = Process.Start(psi);

                        System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader1 = p.StandardOutput;

                        p.WaitForExit();


                        string sOutput = myStreamReader1.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Exactly the same story here. PsExec was outputing just the first line, and not the rest. Tried everything but PaExec fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your sourcecode is correct? that link is quite a bit old.. maybe its fixed!

Heres an example how to redirect the standard-output and put whole output in a string via streamreader:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("tftp.exe");

        // preferences for tftp process
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process p = Process.Start(psi);

        StreamReader myStreamReader = p.StandardOutput;

        p.WaitForExit();

        // Read the standard output of the spawned process.                
        string sOutput = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: hey thx for quick reply.. i tried that and it did not work see my edit above to my original question. it just hung the code and if i commented out createnowindow i saw the window just hang, when i closed it code continue on and it only got the first line oft he ipconfig, so this is a great leap forward :) but not complete. any additional help would be good i spent 2 days on this

Comment: your process starts, but did not waits for exit.(in your latest added code-sample)

Comment: i´ve edited my code-sample. after initializing the streamreader with binding the output you should wait for exit. then you should be able to read to end.

Comment: strange, anytime i use watiforexit(), cmd line just hangs is seems.. if i use close() i get the output, but again if i use just ipconfig from local host i get all the output, if psexec to run ipconfig on remote host i just get first line instead of all output ??? :( i don't know wheter to cry or laugh

Comment: you definitely need the waitforexit-method, because the output needs to be filled. otherwise you read it directly after starting process.. so there cant be any std-ou at this time.
have you ever set CreateNoWindow to false? maybe the psexec-process does not finish without an input?!

Answer (score 0):

psexec's output goes to StandardError and not StandardOutput. I don't know why it is that way. Following code snippet access it.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

process.Close();
```